# No content showing in Taxonomy term template

Tags: panels, caching

I'm having one of those problems that makes no sense, and I've run out of ideas.
I have several pages using Taxonomy term template, and the system works great, as long as views caching is turned off. If I turn on views caching, visitors, and authenticated users see the page as having no content. However the admin can see the page content. I have checked and rechecked all the permissions, and I can't find any reason why cached content is being seen only by the admin, and it happens only on any Taxonomy term template pages.

Comment: Ingesting problem, here are a few questions that might help make this easier to answer: 1) What happens when you clear caches? 2) Presumably you're talking about a vocabulary list page - if this is based on a .tpl.php template, where does the view with the caching settings come into it? 3) Why is this tagged "panels"? Panels isn't mentioned in your question text (or is it a panels page and the views caching setting is in panels not in one view?)

Comment: 1. Nothing changes for anybody. Everybody but the admin sees just the no data notice I added to the view.
2. The view is where the cache is set. It is processed through the 'Taxonomy term template' page that came with Panels.
3.See #2
Thanks. Sorry if I confused.

Comment: The only other clue I have so far is off of the apache error log: Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/vhosts/tlt.com/httpdocs/sites/tlt/themes/tlt/images/. I don't think that has anything to do with it though.

Comment: This issue might be related http://drupal.org/node/1630820

Comment: @mikeytown2 I don't have that enabled, so I don't think so. It would be nice. I'm still fussing with it, trying all different types of cache settings, but it still wont work. I even added a bit of code that displays the user's roles just to be sure that nothing is wrong with them.